# How to get peewee result length

Tags: python, orm, peewee

I use peewee orm in python.

I have a query that :

```
userOrganizations = (UserOrganization
    .select(UserOrganization,Organization)
    .join(Organization)
    .where(UserOrganization.user==user.user_id)
    .aggregate_rows()
)
```

I want to get length of userOrganizations variable. Is there any method like userOrganizations.length() ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [peewee documentation](https://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#counting-records) you can use the `count()` function, i.e.:

`userOrganizations.count()`

If you're worried about maybe running extra DB queries, you can convert your result to a list and get the length, like:

`len(list(userOrganizations))`

Source for second technique: [this question](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/issues/412).

Comment: Until calling list peewee does not run the query. Is that correct?

Comment: That's correct. `list` will evaluate the query. Also, if UserOrganization has a foreign key to Organization, you do not need the `aggregate_rows()` call.